# ngx-markdown inserts <p> tag around markdown

Tags: angular, markdown

I'm trying to use ngx-markdown in an Angular app to render some markdown. When I first set it up it was working and...

`<markdown>#heading</markdown>`
produced:
`<h1>heading</h1>`

Great! But, I must have messed something up, because it now renders: `<markdown><p>#heading</p></markdown>`

What did I mess up? Why are paragraph `<p>` tags suddenly appearing in the markup?

Comment: well, what did you change? please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: p.s. you sure you don't need a space after the `#`? i.e. `# heading`

Comment: Markdown requires a space between the hash and your heading text. Otherwise it is interpreted as normal text.

Comment: Well, now this is embarrassing. It's always the minute details. Thank you guys!